# App for launching activity

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App just for launching an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985792/app-just-for-launching-an-activity)

I'm trying to add a shortcut to launch Sound Recorder on App Drawer (not home screen)

So the app should be empty and the only work it has to do is launch Sound Recorder
com.android.soundrecorder/com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder

How can I do that?

I get Force Stop with this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="recorder.audio.dsaif"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Recorder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recorder" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the java file

```
package recorder.audio.dsaif;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Recorder extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recorder);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_recorder, menu);
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: Whats the error.? Why you are using _setContentView()_ after the startActivity.!

Comment: Removed setContentView.. still force closes

Comment: at which line, it force closes.!

Comment: open the logcat and copy paste that in your question.

Comment: CommonsWare, it's not a possible duplicate , it's a real duplicate , by the same user . maybe there he asked for it in general and now specifically for the sound recorder .